# How to avoid the road bike physique

Tags: road-bike, health, fitness, nutrition

Due to a house move I am soon to become a road bike commuter with approx. 18 miles to cover. I could do with loosing a few kgs but am worried about developing the emaciated physique so apparent in many of the road bikers I see. How can one avoid this? Is it simply a product of the high endurance aspects of road cycling over longer distances, or a combination of that and excessive dieting? I have been a mountain biker for over 10 years and have found that it helps one build muscle mass in the upper thigh and arms and shoulders. Any advice on how to avoid the skinny road biker look would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: 18 miles each way I assume? Certainly I lost weight on 19 miles total but a daily dose of cake kept that in reasonable limits and is thoroughly recommended. Don't forget that competitive (even just strava KoM) road riders have a real incentive to keep the weight down

Comment: Professional road bikers ride way more than 36 miles a day, and they do not ride at commuting pace. They also have a complete working out routine and diet, so I'd not worry too much. If you balance the extra calorie expenditure in your daily diet, you should not loose any weight. If your concerns are really that much, consult with a qualified nutritionist and complement your exercise with arms, shoulders and upper core specific routines.

Comment: Just eat a lot.

Comment: For about 10 years I did about 15 miles to work and 10 back.  I was leaner than now, but not by much.

Comment: Eviscerated is a bit harsh, no? Unless someone has just been through a particularly bad crash. Perhaps you meant emaciated?

Comment: After 3 years solid road commuting (5000-8000 km/year) the most significant changes have been an increase in lung capacity, and an increase in calf muscles, and a loss of ~50mm off the waistline.  Not enough to notice, but a good gentle improvement to overall health.
In short, **you're overthinking this**

Comment: @Criggie not really, I'm quite a big chap and have worked hard building the muscle I need in the right places. My concern is will I be able to do enough weight training to offset the damage done by all this cycling. Bearing in mind that most of my training time will now be spent commuting on the bike. While I don't doubt the CV benefit, I don't want to resemble most of the road bikers I see around. It's not meant to insult those with exactly this physique, rather that it's not for me (nor my girlfriend :) )

Comment: @Marius you are correct! My autocorrect/poor vocabulary  was clearly under performing here.

Comment: If cycling displaces weights, you'll have to spend your remaining weights time on stuff that doesn't overlap too much with cycling.  You can also consider your options for top-up sessions when you get off the bike press-ups and chin-ups are obvious examples requiring little equipment, you'll know better than me what fits your training routine. I actually improved my upper body strength (never thought too much about physique) when I had a longer bike commute, because I seem to respond well to little-and-often training, and spent 20-40 minutes in the gym every day between my ride and my shower.

Comment: Wait, but I thought the "only eats celery sticks" look was what everyone was going for these days?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Roughly, your muscles are made up of two types of muscle fibers: fast and slow.

Slow muscle fibers are relatively weak, but they have very high endurance. Long rides at moderate effort level will burn fat and develop your slow muscle fibers.

Fast fibers are... well, much faster, much stronger, but they have much lower endurance. These are the ones you use when sprinting, or doing reps/lifting weights. They also have more bulk, so they're the ones usually associated with the "muscle look".

If you don't work the fast fibers, you'll look like a climber cyclist or a marathon runner (and you'll suck at sprints). If you only work the fast ones, you'll look like a track sprinter with huge thighs. It is good to develop both, aim somewhere in-between. Basically look at pro cyclists, there is not an extra gram of useless body mass on these guys, so pick one you like, check if he's a climber or a sprinter, and train accordingly.

A nice way to do this on a bike is to sprint between traffic lights. This is basically HIIT. It's fun, too. Makes you sweat a lot, so do it on the way home! Pull on the handlebars to work your arms too...

but if you don't want the "cyclist arms", you gonna have to either lift a bit or do some rough MTB, which is a good workout.

Answer (score 14):

This would be a great problem to have for most of us roadies. Simply eat more if you find yourself losing more weight than you care to lose.

You can alternatively balance with more strength based exercises like lifts, pulls, rows at the gym or elsewhere.

Or cake.

Comment: or beer, lots of beer. A staple of Mountain biker's rigorous diets :P

Comment: True, it was more that I was concerned about it being an inevitable side effect of road biking. I already train quite a bit so hopefully this should offset any muscle loss. And good point about the beer!

Comment: Careful with that beer, good way to become one of those "old guys who get fat in winter"

Comment: Cider is better - its at least vaguly fruit-based.

Comment: @CardMechanic so don't be a fair-weather cyclist, then you can drink all year round

Answer (score 5):

Elite cyclists work very, *very* hard for that emaciated physique! It's not exactly natural -- they're working to drop as much unnecessary weight as possible in order to climb faster. While I think bike commuting should help make you leaner, you won't look anything like Bradley Wiggins unless you're also restricting your diet and training very hard. Don't worry!

Comment: Saying that I do see an awful lot of Wiggins look alikes on my daily commute!

Answer (score 4):

+1 on the weight work. I read of a report that demonstrated reduced bone density in professional cyclists, attributed to the very smooth loading/unloading of stress on the leg bones in the pedaling cycle. Google for it. My wife's doctor recommended to her impact exercise (weights, running, etc.) because she's under 115lbs and normal walking doesn't stress her bones enough to delay/offset/combat osteopenia. FWIW I'm 63, 5'-7", 145lbs, upper body like Gimondi. :)